# Pandas transform rows with specific character

Tags: pandas, dataframe

i am working on features transformation, and ran into this issue. Let me know what you think. Thanks!

[I have a table like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDT6g.png)

[And I want to create an output column like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUFew.png)

Some info:

1. All the outputs will be based on numbers that end with a ':'
2. I have 100M+ rows in this table. Need to consider performance issue.

Let me know if you have some good ideas. Thanks!

Here is some copy and paste-able sample data:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'Number': {0: '1000',1: '1000021', 2: '15:00', 3: '23424234',
  4: '23423', 5: '3', 6 : '9:00', 7: '3423', 8: '32', 9: '7:00'}})
```

Comment: you need to do two things. Look for string pattern with : in it, then copy it over to a new column. Then do a ffill so it gets the values copied over.

Comment: A good way to ask question is not to put a link to your source file and instead provide the data as text information. Also, have you tried out any code to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you update your question with sample data and output as I have done in my answer to make this a proepr question? Thank you! I have included some data in your question as an example. You can use copy your data  from excel and run `pd.read_clipboard().to_dict()`. Then you can paste that dictionary within `df = pd.DataFrame()` Also, please show what you have attempted.

Comment: @JoeFerndz Appreciated the note! Will do next time ;)

Comment: @DavidErickson Thanks for the info! Will do next time, cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution #1:
You can use `.str.contains(':')` with `np.where()` to identify the values, otherwise return `np.nan`. Then, use `ffill()` to fill down on `nan` values:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Number': {0: '1000',1: '1000021', 2: '15:00', 3: '23424234',
  4: '23423', 5: '3', 6 : '9:00', 7: '3423', 8: '32', 9: '7:00'}})
df['Output'] = np.where(df['Number'].str.contains(':'),df['Number'].str.split(':').str[0],np.nan)
df['Output'] = df['Output'].ffill()
df
```

Solution #2 - Even easier and potentially better performance you can do some regex with `str.extract()` and then again `ffill()`:

```
df['Output'] = df['Number'].str.extract('^(\d+):').ffill()
df


Out[1]: 
     Number Output
0      1000    NaN
1   1000021    NaN
2     15:00     15
3  23424234     15
4     23423     15
5         3     15
6      9:00      9
7      3423      9
8        32      9
9      7:00      7
```

Comment: Solution 2 is quite interesting. It can save a lot of time. Almost 1ms is saved in the dataframe you took as a sample.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
import pandas as pd
c = ['Number']
d = ['1:00',100,1001,1321,3254,'15:00',20,60,80,90,'4:00',26,45,90,89]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d,columns=c)

temp= df['Number'].str.split(":", n = 1, expand = True)

df['New_Val'] = temp[0].ffill()

print(df)
```

The output of this will be as follows:

```
   Number New_Val
0    1:00       1
1     100       1
2    1001       1
3    1321       1
4    3254       1
5   15:00      15
6      20      15
7      60      15
8      80      15
9      90      15
10   4:00       4
11     26       4
12     45       4
13     90       4
14     89       4
```

Looks like your DataFrame has string values. I considered them as a mix of numbers and strings.

Here's the solution if `df['Number']` is all strings.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Number': {0: '1000',1: '1000021', 2: '15:00', 3: '23424234',
  4: '23423', 5: '3', 6 : '9:00', 7: '3423', 8: '32', 9: '7:00'}})

temp= df1['Number'].str.split(":", n = 1, expand = True)
temp.loc[temp[1].astype(bool) != False, 'New_val'] = temp[0]

df1['New_val'] = temp['New_val'].ffill()

print (df1)
```

The output of `df1` will be:

```
     Number New_val
0      1000     NaN
1   1000021     NaN
2     15:00      15
3  23424234      15
4     23423      15
5         3      15
6      9:00       9
7      3423       9
8        32       9
9      7:00       7
```